# Resolving yum package dependency without actually reinstalling dependency

Tags: centos-7

Is there any way to tell Centos that I don't *care* about a missing dependency in my yum database?

Specifically, consider `sudo`, which requires `/usr/bin/vi`.  Uninstalling `vim-minimal` (which provides `/usr/bin/vi`) also uninstalls `sudo`.  Installing `vim-enhanced` (which is what I actually want) provides `/usr/bin/vim` not `/usr/bin/vi`.

I get that `visudo` needs an editor.  `ln [-s] /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vi` fulfills the requirement to all acceptable standards I've come across.

**So why does `package-cleanup --problems` continue to care about `/usr/bin/vi`?**  As far as anything else is concerned, that file exists.

I've seen plenty of posts, questions, bug reports, etc. requesting that the package be changed (all of which seem to be ten years old, closed and/or ignored) but this still seems to be a *thing*.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
# package-cleanup --problems
Package sudo-1.8.23-3.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of /usr/bin/vi
# ls -l /usr/bin/vi*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      12 Jan 21 23:57 /usr/bin/vi -> /usr/bin/vim*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2294208 Oct 30 19:57 /usr/bin/vim*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       3 Jan 19 03:06 /usr/bin/vimdiff -> vim*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    2084 Oct 30 19:57 /usr/bin/vimtutor*
```

(Just an irritation...)

Comment: Change teh control file for one or the other RPMs, either to accept `vi` or `vim` or to state that it is providing both `vi` and `vim`.

Comment: @ivanivan - is that something *I* can do, as the user of my system; or something that the *distro* should do as the provider of the package...?  If it is something *I* can do, can you elaborate as to *how*?

Comment: Should be able to do it for yourself, although you'll need `root` access to install of course.  May want to file it as a bug to the package maintainer as well, either for the `vim` (since it is providing a `vi` command) or for the `sudo` package since ANY editor should be valid to use with `visudo`.  If you care to do it yourself check out https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-advanced-packaging.html